# C# - A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or invalid when run from localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, antiforgerytoken

We have an application which includes anti forgery token and works fine when hosted them on web farms. We are now newly hosting our application in to another servers. When we try to run the same application in the new server as localhost we are getting anti-forgery token error.

Application setup and configuration are same in both the servers. but still I get this issue. I am getting RequestVerificationToken in the web form as well as in cookie too. We have machinekey included in web.config file with SHA1 validation and AES decryption.

Can anyone suggest whey are we getting this issue